# Asp.net api url authentication like php http authentication

Tags: php, asp.net, authentication

We have a php application with an API, this application allow us to login using this form in the url in the address bar of browser:

https://user:password@mycompany.com/ApiMethod?ApiParameter=info

How can I use this type of login in asp.net?

This is for legacy porpuses in a new system.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

`$_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER']` and `$_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_PW']` will contains the credentials of a successfully received basic-auth request.

http://php.net/manual/en/features.http-auth.php